# How can I programmatically add an autolayout constraint to make a button 50 points above bottom of its superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm struggling to figure out how to use VFL to accomplish this. I always want the button to be 50 points above the bottom of its superview. I don't want to specify the distance between the top of the bottom and the top of its superview because that will vary across devices.

I was only able to find other similar questions using interface builder, but my project does not use interface builder or swift, but I would like to do this programmatically, in Objective-C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
[yourSuperView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:yourSuperView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-50.0]];
```

You can read more on this here: [Working with Auto Layout Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html)

Comment: I didn't think to make the constant negative. Of course! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no idea about how to use VFL, I think you should check the document:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
NSArray *constraints=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-50-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)];
// add more constraints to satisfy auto layout
[superview addConstraints:constraints];
```

BTW, I recommend to use Masonry, https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry, it's more elegant.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is how I ultimately ended up doing it. I previously didn't know that I could use only one pipe in VFL. All the examples and tutorials I saw always used two pipes in the constraints argument, and I mistakenly assumed that I also had to use two, which kept me stumped for a while. Thank you again!